# Avoid getting OneDrive search results for local files

Tags: search, windows-10, onedrive

In Windows 10, how can I avoid getting search results that link to files online in OneDrive (and open a web browser when you click them) when those files also reside locally? I want just the local files, so that when I choose a result, the local app opens.

For background, here the problem report I submitted via the Windows 10 Feedback app:

> For OneDrive files that also reside locally, the search results show
>   the online version first.
>
> This isn't a problem with searching file names, but it is with
>   searching file contents. For example, suppose I have a file in
>   "OneDrive\Documents" named "Mustelidae.doc", which includes the word
>   "weasel". The file exists in the cloud and on my hard drive. If I type
>   "weasel" into Search, the first results are
>   "OneDrive:\Documents\Mustelidae.doc" along with all my other OneDrive
>   files with "weasel" in them. Finally, almost completely scrolled off
>   the screen, are the same documents listed again under the heading
>   "This Device". The "Mustelidae.doc" in that list is the one I want,
>   since it will open Word, not a web page.
>
> If you really want to be smart about this, keep the OneDrive section
>   (since OneDrive files are usually more relevant than files outside
>   OneDrive) but detect the files are available locally, and have the
>   items in the OneDrive section link locally. Then exclude the
>   duplicates from the "This Device" section. If you don't have time to
>   go that far, at least provide an option to turn off the "OneDrive"
>   section of the results.

Comment: I just experienced this for the first time this evening, very frustrating. I searched for song, Cortana found it, but when I clicked the file name my browser opened up. Another case of Microsoft almost getting it right but actually taking a retrograde step from Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

To disable search from OneDrive files go to Search-settings and disable clound content search:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out. When you get the seach result, don't left-click, right-click instead and click open file location. that opens win explorer with the file highlighted. So then immediately click enter and it opens locally!!!!

Comment: This doesn't disable getting search results for non-local files.  This just describes, opening the folder location of a file in the search results, which has not actually changed.